# How can I use Stack Overflow's wiki features?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I am new to Stack Overflow (and your planet) so I would like to ask how and where can I use Stack Overflow's wiki features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question or answer that is Community wiki has a lower reputation threshold for editing. And you won't get any reputation change for up and downvotes. Although you get the badges (and bounties that are awarded).

If you like your answer to be community wiki, check the checkbox.

If you like your question to be community wiki, flag for moderator support and ask for community wiki.

Remember that you can't go back so this is a one way trip.

Comment: How can i add Wiki community with me

Comment: @Nikki You need to flag a post for moderation attention, requesting it to be converted. Users cannot create community wiki themselves.